# Why is mouseover function not working

Tags: javascript, html, image, mouseover

I have the simplest of codes, but I've never tried using onmouseover before, so not sure why it's not working:

```
<div class="play" id="buttonPlay">
    <img src="Buttons/Play/playRest.png" onmouseover="this.src='Buttons/Play/playClick.png'" width="100%"> 
</div>
```

Any ideas? And what would be a good way to go about debugging it?

Comment: I copied the code replaced with an `alert()` and the alert shows, so it should be running.

Comment: [Open the browser's JS console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) and see what the error messages are.

Comment: Define "not working". Is the image replaced with a broken image? Are error message displayed in the console? Does nothing happen at all?

Comment: Does that code really reproduce the problem? Or does it only occur when (for example) other HTML elements and CSS are added?

Comment: No, it's not working at all. No errors on the console. I also tried replacing with alert() and still no.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try declaring your function in a script element and reference to that function instead of doing it all inline. At least that way you can set Breakpoint in the developper console of your browser and see what is happening.

```
<div class="play" id="buttonPlay">
    <img src="Buttons/Play/playRest.png" onmouseover="myFunction(this)" width="100%"> 
</div>
<script>
    function myFunction(element) {
        element.src='Buttons/Play/playClick.png';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Re edit: Now you aren't breaking it, but you don't seem to have solved the problem. You are just suggesting a line of debugging. (It would be easier to set a breakpoint by prepending `debugger;` to the `onmouseover` attribute value)

Comment: @Quentin you're right, I edited it, but it's not a solution it's just a way to facilitate debugging.

Answer (score -2):

Try using setAttribute instead, when I do so, this works.

```
<div class="play" id="buttonPlay">
    <img src="Buttons/Play/playRest.png" onmouseover="this.setAttribute('src', 'Buttons/Play/playClick.png');" width="100%"> 
</div>
```